# Find words in a string with characters that are repeated

Tags: c++, string, char

I was given the task to remove all extra spaces (should remain 1) and output only those words in which the letters are repeated. I've been sitting for a week and can't find the error, maybe this will help me)))
I've figured out the whitespace, but the word formatting I can't do((

Please help me find a bug in my code

If I enter *I like to play soccer every day*, the program should output *soccer every*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

char str[128];
printf("Write String: ");
fgets(str, 128, stdin);


int i = 0, j;


i = 0;

int start = i;
while (str[i] != '\0') 
{ 
    if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n') 
    { 
        int end = i;

        int first = start;
        int first2 = start + 1;
        int last = end - 1;
        while (first < last) 
        { 
            for (first; first < last; first++)
            {
                for (first2; first2 < last; first2++)
                {
                    if ((str[first] == str[first2]) && (first != first2))
                    { 

                        break; 
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if((first == last - 1) && (first2 == last - 1))
                        {
                            for (j = start; str[end] != '\0'; ++end)
                            {
                                str[j] = str[end + 1];
                                j += 1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (i != start) 
        {
            start = i + 1;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ++i; 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you provide some examples of inputs and expected outputs for them?

Comment: To process a word at a time, read a word at a time: `std::string word; while (std::cin >> word) /* process word */`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

- read your input one word at a time, and
- check if each word has a repeated letter. If it does, print the word.

Now, how to read the input one word at a time. In the example below I've used a `std::istringstream`, but `std::cin` would do.

And, how to check if a word has a repeated letter. A simple, surely not the fastest, way is to create a set from an input string, and check if the set and the string don't have the same number of letters. I've used a lambda for `has_a_repeated_letter` but a function would do.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/WYfrG4b96)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"I like to play soccer every day"};

    auto has_a_repeated_letter = [](const std::string& word) {
        std::set<char> letters{ word.begin(), word.end() };
        return letters.size() != word.size();
    };

    std::string word{};
    while (iss >> word) {
        if (has_a_repeated_letter(word)) {
            std::cout << word << " ";
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   soccer every
```

Comment: There’s no need to save all the words before examining them. Just read a word and process it. Repeat until done.

Comment: Good choice to use `std::istringstream` instead of `std::cin` with instructions on what to type in. This makes the example self-contained.

Comment: How do I need to change the code to fulfill another condition? (I was given an extra job, and everything I do doesn't work). If a string consists of words of equal length, then put an exclamation mark at the beginning of the string, shifting the original string one character to the right. Example: Input: 1)asdfgh asdfgk kjhgfd hlkjhg 2)jhggk akjhs kjh kjh khkjh Output: 1)!asdfgh asdfgk kjhgfd hlkjhg 2)jhggk akjhs kjh kjh khkjh  (1 and 2 are string numbers)

Comment: @GentlyBarry This is a completely different question. Please ask it in another post. Thanks!